# Matrix operation in an Attention Mechanism

Tags: machine-learning, math, matrix, transformer-model

I am reading an article dealing with Transformer Machine Learning models applied to finance. I am trying to understand the math behind the architecture, but I failed to understand this part :

[image]
[image]

Especially, I don't get why the dimensions are not matching between the operations.
According to my comprehension:

1. **step (8)** : *u* should be *M(d_model, 1)*
2. **step (9)** : this should not be possible as the matrix    multiplication dimensions does not match to perform the operation:
   *M(d_model, K) . M(1,d_model)*

Here is the full part of the study :

[image]

I guess, I am missunderstanding something with this notation [image]
or with the *"non-linearly project the matrix M to u"* sentence.

Can someone enlighten me about this, please ?

> **Transformer-based attention network for stock movement prediction**, 2022,
> *Qiuyue Zhang, Chao Qin, Yunfeng Zhang , Fangxun Bao, CaimingZhang, Peide Liu*

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the code or you reach the authors, with this piece of text we have to guess where the error is.

My guess

1. $W_m^M$ in the equation, is $W_m^M$
2. The softmax output is actually computing $u^T$, not $u$
3. eq. 9 should be $M^T u^T$, instead of $M u^T$

Another hypothesis is that they had the equations as described, they had a working code, and when writing the paper they worked out the dimension of the matrices incorrectly.

I don't know if I would trust a paper with publication date in the future, and zero citations.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0957417422006170#!
[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your great answer ! I will reach the authors and try to address them the issue. Great, I did not notice the publication date lol